# Matplotlib error when running plotting function within a larger script on azure

Tags: python, azure, matplotlib, latex

I'm having some trouble running my python script on an Azure virtual machine.
I have a script that accepts inputs from the user from a web page, the script does some calculations and is then meant to plot the output. However, when I run the script through the web request I get a latex related error from matplotlib (! LaTeX Error: File `type1cm.sty' not found). I have installed latex through pip and on the virtual machine and tried the tex=False commands.

Interestingly, when I run the plotting script itself, it works fine. It's just when it's called within the larger programme do I get the error. Also, the plotting function simply plots x- and y-coordinates and doesn't contain any LaTeX.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you might have two conflicting tex distributions. Compare which binaries are used when you run the script itself vs. when your program runs it

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by installing `texlive-full` command, only if you have enough space in your disk.

Apart from that try to locate the file which is not found, you can use below command:

```
locate type1cm.sty
```

So now if it is not installed, which means its not under our configuration. This seems like some dependency packages are missing.

Search of packages and install them

```latex
$ sudo apt-get -y install texlive-latex-recommended texlive-pictures texlive-latex-extra
```

Also installing `texlive-full` is recommended

Comment: Okay, but how would this explain the script working on its own on the VM as opposed to not working as part of a larger set of scripts on the same VM? Thanks.